# Histories of the Universe under Different Initial Conditions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, cosmology, education, quantum-interpretations, observable-universe

The history of the evolution of the Universe (we are talking about the observable part) on ultra-large scales (larger than the scale of galactic superclusters) under any initial conditions would be approximately the same, since this evolution depends on the same laws of physics. However, for different initial conditions, the details of evolution on smaller scales (from the scales of superclusters to individual atoms) would be radically different. In other words, if the initial conditions of our Universe were slightly different, it would be completely different, ranging from the scales of superclusters to individual atoms.

And so, my teacher, quoting several well-known cosmologists and other specialists (Vilenkin, Green, Tegmark, and so on), said that although the number of different variants of the evolution of the observed Universe is unimaginably huge, this number is finite, since in a finite region of space there is only a finite the number of configurations that can appear after decoherence.

What does it mean? Why the number of possible stories is finite. Doesn't this mean that the "MWI's universal wave function of the Universe" should contain only a finite number of terms?

Comment: At least with reference to the "cosmology" aspect of the question, the number of possible histories of the universe being limited to our observable region would seem to account for their number being finite:  There's no observational or experimental way to tell what (very possibly infinitesimal) part of the universe our observable region would comprise, at least if  we're assuming "universe" means "everything", rather than some "local universe" (ours) in the context of a "multiverse".  (However, my knowledge of QM remains too limited to post this remark as an answer.)

Comment: @Edouard I'm ashamed, but I didn't understand anything from your answer ((((

Comment: Well, it just amounts to a remark saying that the finite size of the observable region would leave it containing only a finite number of things, if those things would be limited to quanta (smallest possible units).  I don't know whether the Many Worlds Interpretation makes that assumption.

Comment: @Edouard Well, I'm not sure if the finiteness of the region implies the finiteness of the number of configurations.

Comment: I tend to agree with you there, as I believe that space is infinitely divisible:  However, at least some versions of quantum mechanics seem to make an assumption that space is NOT infinitely divisible, which I think may have been what your teacher was trying to get at, if they brought up the Many Worlds Interpretation.  My belief's only based on a lack of evidence to the contrary.

Comment: If you add the tag "Many Worlds Interpretation", you'll probably get responses from people better informed about MWI:  A question can have up to 5 tags.